# UISearchController doesn't move my UITableView up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uisearchcontroller

As you can see, my `UITableView`'s scroll is maximum down, but my table is not fully visible. Why? I use `UITableViewController`

[image]

Comment: set this as soon as keyboard appears ` tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 200, 0);` and after keyboard disappears set ` table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Do you know, how to get the height of the keyboard? Because the height is different for both orientations. Without using notifications? Is it possible to current visible keyboard?

Answer (score 7):

Good alternative to Ortwin's answer is to use `keyboardDismissMode` property of `UIScrollView`:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag
```

**Swift 4.1**

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to simply hide the keyboard as soon as the user starts scrolling. Apple implements this behavior in their own apps. To do that, add in your table view controller:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This requires a `searchBar` property that is populated with the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

using notifications might be easiest way to get the keyboard height as i commented set `contentInset` property to scroll the tableview above the keyboard, once it hides set to zero insects,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animate
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animate];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardShown:) 
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(keyboardHidden:)
                                               name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  //remove notifications
}


- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
  NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
  CGRect keyboardRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

  float height = keyboardRect.size.height;
  tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, height, 0); 
}

- (void)keyboardHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }];
}
```