# UISearchBar colliding cell contents in UITableView with sections

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController...

[image: View hierarchy]

I'm using a UISearchController to give me a search bar and setting this to the table's header view. I'm also using sections in the UITableView. My problem is, on first presentation, the table header collides with the first cell...

[image: search bar collision]

After search bar has been activated once and then dismissed, the table renders as I expect it to...

[image: search bar rendering without collision]

The code code looks like...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.table.dataSource = self
    self.table.delegate = self
    self.table.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar

    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
}
```

... and this style works fine in other tables which do not have sections.

Comment: Does the answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916323/uisearchcontroller-doesnt-move-my-uitableview-up) help?

Comment: I don't think this is an insets problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future users, setting the table rows to have automatic height fixed this problem...

```
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: In my case all that was necessary was `table.estimatedRowHeight = table.rowHeight` (the latter set from NIB).